# Having trouble plotting. Here is my code:

Tags: plotting, manipulate

[image]

Nothing is plotting when I try to run the code

Comment: Your function is defined improperly (use `L[A_]:=`) and the `Plot` needs to be inside the Manipulate.

Comment: Your range for `{K, .5, .5, .5}` looks wrong

Comment: You should comp and paste the code in next time.

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[
Plot[F*(1 - Exp[-K (A - S)]), {A, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 50}], {S,
1, 5, 1}, {F, 40, 50, 1}, {K, .5, .5, .5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)
```

For a control with a small number of discrete values, a `ControlType` of either `SetterBar` or `PopupMenu` may be a better choice than a `Slider`. The following enables selection of each control type for comparison. The controls do not need to be all of the same type. You can mix and match to taste.

```
Manipulate[
 Manipulate[
  Plot[
   F*(1 - Exp[-K (A - S)]),
   {A, 0, 100},
   PlotRange -> pltRng],
  {{S, 3}, 1, 5, 1, ControlType -> controlS, 
   If[controlS === Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled", Nothing]},
  {{F, 45}, 40, 50, 1, ControlType -> controlF, 
   If[controlF === Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled", Nothing]},
  {{K, 0.5}, 0, 1, .25, ControlType -> controlK, 
   If[controlK === Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled", Nothing]}],
 Row[{
   Control[{{controlS, SetterBar, "S"},
     {SetterBar, PopupMenu, Slider}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}],
   Spacer[20],
   Control[{{controlF, PopupMenu, "F"},
     {SetterBar, PopupMenu, Slider}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}],
   Spacer[20],
   Control[{{controlK, SetterBar, "K"},
     {SetterBar, PopupMenu, Slider}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]}],
 Delimiter,
 {{pltRng, {0, 50}, "Plot Range"}, {{0, 50}, Automatic, Full}}]
```

[image]